# Custom CustomerEndPoint Broadleaf

Tags: api, rest, broadleaf-commerce

I am new to broadleaf. I want to create a custom customerEndPoint Class which will provide services like registering customer getting a customer details etc. I tried creating a CustomerEndpoint Class in com.mycompany.api.endpoint.customer package. Is there any other configurations to be done to access the customer urls??

Please help on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this, Sharing it as it may be helpful for someone. 
I Configured the CustomerEndPoint bean in applicationContent-rest-api.xml and annotated CustomerEndpoint as controller and just extented the BaseEndPoint.

CustomerEndpoint.java

```
@Controller
@Scope("singleton")
@Path("/customer/")
@Produces(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Consumes(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public class CustomerEndpoint extends BaseEndpoint {
@Resource(name = "blCustomerService")
protected CustomerService customerService;

public void setCustomerService(CustomerService customerService) {
    this.customerService = customerService;
}

@GET
public CustomerWrapper getCustomer(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
        @QueryParam("id") String emailId) {
    CustomerWrapper customerWrapper = new CustomerWrapper();
    if (emailId != null && emailId != "") {
        customerWrapper.wrapDetails(
                customerService.readCustomerByEmail(emailId), request);
    }
    return customerWrapper;
}
```

}

applicationContext-rest-api.xml

```
<bean id="customerEndpoint" class="com.mycompany.api.endpoint.customer.CustomerEndpoint"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends of whatever version are you using. If you using for example : broadleaf-3.1.X see
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.broadleafcommerce/broadleaf-framework/3.1.5-GA

You could take as an example `com.mycompany.api.endpoint.checkout.CheckoutEndpoint`.

Into default platform there is `org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.api.endpoint.customer.CustomerEndpoint` but this implementation is empty.

You could extend that class and add annotation similar to `com.mycompany.api.endpoint.checkout.CheckoutEndpoint` also add business logic according to your needs.

There isn't some platform default implementation into platform as far as I can see int broadleaf-3.1.6-GA

Comment: Thanks for your input. I extended the BaseEndpoint class and ignored org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.api.endpoint.customer.CustomerEndpoint as it doesn't provide anything.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you. In future you could take as example another similar class and go with your specific implementation